# Pegar ultimo key do auto increment PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estou com um problema quanto ao meu sistema que esta o seguinte,

```
try {
$sql = "SELECT Nid+1 AS Nid  FROM noticias ORDER BY Nid DESC LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":Nid", intval($_GET["Nid"]));

$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$Npasta = $results[0]["Nid"];

} catch (Exception $ex) {
echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Estou pegando o ultimo ID registrado e criando uma pasta com o mesmo numero porem quando eu excluo o ultimo id a contagem passa a ser errada pois EX: inseri o id 998, apos inserir apaguei, no proximo que irei inserir ele ira pegar 998 novamente , onde o certo era pegar o id 999; Alguma luz sobre isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pesquisando sobre o assunto achei esse metodo que é na minha opiniao o mais seguro pois ele pega diretamente o valor do auto_increment segue o codigo final do problema resolvido

```
try {
$sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'nomedatabela' ";  
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->fetch();
$proximoID = $results['Auto_increment'];  // a chave esta aqui
} catch (Exception $ex) {
 echo $ex->getMessage();
}
echo "$proximoID";
```

Feito isso mesmo que seja deletado o id ele vai sempre buscar o proximo a ser inserido

Comment: Seguro não é, se tiver duas tabelas com nomes parecidos ...

Comment: Quando disse seguro, disse em questao de realmente pegar o proximo ID da forma mais segura possivel pois é o proprio auto increment, quanto a consulta tambem pode se tornar mais seguro caso use outro metodo

Answer (score 2):

As duas saidas menos ruins para esse problema, que eu vejo são:

1) Crie uma coluna chamada `excluido` ou `ativo` pode ser bit ou boolean, no lugar de deletar o registro, faça um update nessa coluna, isso resolve parcialmente o problema de buracos na sequência.

2) Crie uma nova tabela com duas colunas uma o id e a outra o valor do último insert, para cada registro grave na sua tabela principal e nessa nova e sempre faça a leitura do último valor nessa tabela.

Comment: Ao invés desta coluna, em um trabalho de faculdade, fui orientado a fazer uma tabela extra de auditoria, onde eu salvaria tudo que fosse excluído. Essa sugestão também é boa?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, a tabela extra do seu trabalho me parece estar em outro contexto, no de log operações. Na resposta sugerir ela para evitar um delete, então para trazer todas as noticias 'não excluidas' seria algo assim, `select * from noticias where excluida = false`

Answer (score 2):

Caso a tabela tenha uma chave primária com *autoincrement* você pode consultar o valor do próximo registro que será inserido com a consulta abaixo, pois o valor do `AUTO_INCREMENT` não é alterado por exclusões de linhas.

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
AND TABLE_NAME = 'noticias';
```

Essa maneira deve fazer o mesmo efeito do `Nid+1` da pergunta.

Comment: Parece a melhor opção :)

Comment: é bem isso mesmo vou testar aqui

Comment: mais aqui nao entendi como vou selecionar o campo que pego o ID pois em nenhum momento ai da sua consulta vc informou qual é o campo ( no meu caso Nid). SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM tabela esse Where serve para q?

Comment: ele retorna o valor da propriedade `AUTO_INCREMENT` da tabela, o campo não é mencionado na consulta porque depende da definição dos campos, no seu caso vai funcionar se o campo `Nid` tiver a propriedade `AUTO_INCREMENT` ativa